# How to compile directive manually?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive, angularjs-scope

I have this code

```
<input type="text" name="firstName" ng-model="data.firstName" required>
```

But I want to make a directive to simplify it like this

```
<my-field name="firstName"></my-field>
```

Here is my plnkr link: http://plnkr.co/edit/XYk5MmE3YzKxvAHQgoZp?p=preview

Two questions
1. How to make my field work like the original input
2. Is it possible to use the template property in this case?

Thanks

Comment: are you asking if it is possible or something else?

Comment: I believe the OP wants some direction on how to accomplish the task at hand

Comment: I'm sure it's possible but my implementation doesn't work and I don't know why. Check the Plnkr

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've solved it myself: http://plnkr.co/edit/XYk5MmE3YzKxvAHQgoZp?p=preview

I added manually the `name` and `ng-model` attributes and then I recompiled the element.

Comment: I don't think it s a good solution, you saying you don't want to hardcode but you did it at your example...

Comment: It's not hardcoded at all. Check out these liness `element[0].setAttribute('name', name);` `element[0].setAttribute('ng-model', 'data.' + name);`

Answer (score 0):

In your code, you don't have to do a custom compile just to set the model values.

For getting values like ng-model, you can require ngModel in your custom directive.

An example implementation using ngModel is the date picker directive

https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-date

Comment: I don't need a new scope for it, I just need to replace the html code.

Comment: http://plnkr.co/edit/CdM29mz7Gh4UpwhsGUWR?p=preview Please see the updated Plnkr. We can just use a replace

Answer (score 0):

check this [PLUNKER](http://plnkr.co/edit/ZbkSr45OeOY3cyhFqESQ?p=preview)...

you can define your directive variables as you want, here I just use **myFieldVar** to pass variable to your directive, you don't care about variable name in scope as you see in template

I use `ng-model="myFieldVar"` so whatever scope variable you bind to **my-field-var** in html you can use it with that name...

**UPDATE**

If you do not want to use new scope then add **scope : true** to your directive options but in this case you are only doing replace your directive tag with your template...

here is updated [PLUNKER](http://plnkr.co/edit/ZbkSr45OeOY3cyhFqESQ?p=preview)

Comment: I need to set both: name and ng-model and also I don't need a new scope.